# NestJs-Swagger - Is it possible to list all Swagger Documents in a NestExpressApplication?

Tags: swagger, nestjs

I'm using **NestJs** with the **SwaggerModule** and I want to list all documents after the application initialization.

Something like:

```
[
  {
    title: 'Admin',
    description: 'Admin endpoints',
    version: '1.2.3',
    url: 'admin/123/'
  },
  {
    title: 'Resources',
    description: 'Resources endpoints',
    version: '1.2.5',
    url: 'admin/125/'
  }
]
```

Is there an object I can reach that have the information of those documents or do I have to create it myself?

Comment: isn't that the `options` you use `DocumentBuilder` to build?

Comment: Yes, but is there a way to access this information from the ```app.service.ts``` for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just looked through `NestJS` docs and there seems to be no way to add a provider at runtime. But it's not impossible.

1. Create a service `SwaggerDocumentService`

```js
@Injectable()
export class SwaggerDocumentService {
   private _swaggerDocuments: Array<Omit<OpenAPIObject, 'components' | 'paths'>>;

   get swaggerDocuments(): Array<Omit<OpenAPIObject, 'components' | 'paths'>> {
      return this._swaggerDocuments;
   }

   addSwaggerDocument(value: Omit<OpenAPIObject, 'components' | 'paths'>): void {
      this._swaggerDocuments.push(value); // you might want to go with immutable way but just to give you an idea
   }
}
```

2. Create a `SwaggerDocumentModule` and make it global. Then provide and export `SwaggerDocumentService` in `SwaggerDocumentModule`

```js
@Global()
@Module({
   providers: [SwaggerDocumentService],
   exports: [SwaggerDocumentService]
})
export class SwaggerDocumentModule
```

3. Import `SwaggerDocumentModule` in `AppModule`

```js
@Module({
   ...
   imports: [SwaggerDocumentModule]
})
export class AppModule
```

4. In `main.ts`, grab the instance of `SwaggerDocumentService` and set the documents.

```js
async bootstrap() {
   const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
   const swaggerDocumentService = app.get<SwaggerDocumentService>(SwaggerDocumentService); // might want to check for null
   // setup your options with DocumentBuilder
   const options = new DocumentBuilder()...;

   swaggerDocumentService.addSwaggerDocument(options);
}
```

5. Use `SwaggerDocumentService`

```js
@Injectable()
export class AppService {
   constructor(private readonly swaggerDocumentService: SwaggerDocumentService) {
      swaggerDocumentService.swaggerDocuments; // will be the array of Swagger Document
   }
}
```